# trouble assigning a const gchar *

Tags: c++, gtk

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here
My struct:

```
struct listItem {const gchar *name,*val1,*val2,*val3;};
```

then later on I do this:

```
listItem *temp;
const gchar *b1 = (const gchar *) (gtk_entry_buffer_get_text(GTK_ENTRY_BUFFER(obgect->b1)));
```

this all works fine but I get a segmentation fault here:

```
temp->name = b1;
```

sorry I suck so bad

Comment: You seem to be showing snippets that have nothing to do with each other. You show us one line involving `temp`, but the next line doesn't involve it. And `obgect` seems to come out of nowhere. Where does `temp` get initialized?

Comment: is  listItem *temp  not an initializer?  I thought after that after that I would be able to assign to it.

Comment: Yes, but you never do assign to it. You dereference it before doing any assignment. You need `temp = <something>` before you can do `temp->something`. You can't dereference a pointer that doesn't point anywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate storage for `temp`, like:

```
listItem temp;
temp.name = b1;
```

Comment: Ok I see, I can not just create a pointer to it and assign with the -> operator, is that correct?

Comment: `listItem *temp = new listItem`. This allocates memory for temp, and then you can use things like `temp->name`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [Binky and his magic wand of dereferencing](http://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=FR&hl=fr&v=6pmWojisM_E)...